# Jenkins build won't fail when it should

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I'm currently working on a Jenkins project that opens a program checks to see if it is running, and sends back a pass/fail. I have an install test and an uninstall test, and this test is supposed to check if the app is installed and can run, or if it is uninstalled to check and make sure it uninstalled properly. It works fine if the program is running, but if it isn't it hangs and only sends back a fail when it times out. It says the path cannot be found in the console output, which should happen because the folder that it's in gets deleted when the application is uninstalled, but for some reason it doesn't send back a fail even though it recognizes this.  Here's my batch command:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\file\file location
start application.exe 
cd c:\windows\system32
sc query rfecosvc
tasklist | find "application"
```

Here is the console output:

```
Started by user justin dunlap
Building remotely on BuildTestSlave (Justin_slave) in workspace C:\workspace\BuildTest2
[BuildTest2] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\rivet\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson4978209418565106916.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.
Build timed out (after 3 minutes). Marking the build as failed.
Build was aborted
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: remove @echo off and see that happens with your batch file

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are some ways to debug this error. You can make a try

1. Remove `@echo` off if you have that at the top of your script
2. Remove any `>nul's` or similar you have for any commands
3. Add a `pause` at the very end of the script

Hope this can help you.

Credit goes to @[Bali C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799586/bali-c)